# Does elective single embryo transfer (eSET) reduce pro-life hangups against IVF?

Tags: medical-science, abortion

On the [Centers for Disease Control website about Elective Single Embryo Transfer or eSET](https://www.cdc.gov/art/patientresources/transfer.html), health experts count the risks of multiple births as including:

> Some who become pregnant with multiples may find one or more cannot survive to term or even a premature birth. This may lead to a medical need to perform fetal reduction.

Obviously, for a pro-lifer, this is a gut-wrenching possibility that would affect their choice of an assisted reproductive technology plan.  Is Elective Single Embryo Transfer, in which the woman or couple chooses to implant only one embryo (instead of multiples) a good way to alleviate this moral hazard?

Comment: Skeptics.SE can't answer questions of morality, only empirical facts.  What is the factual claim you are doubting, and who is making it?

Comment: The factual claim is implied on the CDC website.  Multiples -> Risk.  Solution?  eSET!

Comment: What constitutes a "good" way to alleviate a *moral* (and thus, non-quantifiable) "hazard" is opinion based. Voting to close as such.

Comment: @DevSolar, but there is a firm body of orthodoxy within "that side" that provides an objective ground for analysis... this may be opinion-based, but it's not wishy-washy.

Comment: @DevSolar what's better, nuclear or solar?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "better", which is opinion-based unless you specify more specific conditions. ;-) -- You could ask if eSET results in more pro-life proponents to opt for IVF, but I don't think it will be possible to isolate this from all other variables, and anyway, you'd end up judging by self-assessment questionaires, which (you guessed it) would be opinion-based...

Comment: @DevSolar, IVF writing is ripe with misrepresentation and misleading terminology, and hiding, and the people who have to decide are at every level of education (and desperation).  In addition, the information that's available is frequently written by IVF clinics rather than uninterested third parties (like StackExchange).

Comment: ...and that means, in your opinion...?

Comment: @DevSolar, that means that this subject (with its competing narratives and unclear terminology) is a good place for the smart folks at StackExchange to provide a pubic service and analyze the claims for the benefit of others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88357/discussion-between-devsolar-and-elliot-svensson).

Comment: As it stands, the question is asking about moral hazard, which is opinion based. Asking about a reduction in the risk of performing a fetal reduction is not opinion based. Asking about the effectiveness of this technique in starting a pregnancy is not opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the website says, the one embryo is:

> selected from a larger number of available embryos

So many lives are created, and only one is saved.

Comment: Hm. Whether and from what point onward an embry qualifies as "life" is part of the whole argument, isn't it?

Comment: @DevSolar From a pro-life perspective, which is specified in the question, there is little to debate here and the answer is functional.

Comment: @DevSolar if someone believes that life starts after the stage where the embryos are implanted, but before the number would be reduced, then it would matter to that person.

Comment: As I said, the definition of "life" is part of the whole argument. (Meaning to indicate that the answer would be better if it referred to "embryo" in that last line as well, avoiding the issue altogether and leaving the definition of "life" to the reader.)